# Javascript Popup in same tab

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'm looking for help on a issue im having, ive tried many times to get this working..

I want to be able to open specific popups through the selection of items on a datalist, each item opens its own popup which all have specific forms inside regarding the selection from the user. E.g selecting general fitness and pressing submit opens the general fitness popup.

I have been adding the popups url into the selections but does not open the popups.

The HTML is mine but I have found a script that looks a little like what i need, except this opens a link in a new window. Maybe this can be edited to save time?

Any help would be appreciated!

```js
function goToNewPage() {
  if (document.getElementById('target').value) {
    window.location.href = document.getElementById('target').value;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <form name="dropdown">
      <select name="selected" id="target" accesskey="E">
        <option selected>Select...</option>
        <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
        <option value="http://www.search.com/">Search.com</option>
        <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/">Dogpile</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.selected)">
    </form>

    <form>
      <div class="form-box">
        <input list="category" class="search-field category" placeholder="What service are you looking for?">
        <datalist id="category">
                    <input type="hidden">
  <option value="General Fitness">
  <option value="Boxing">
  <option value="Yoga">
  <option value="Mixed Martial Arts">
  <option value="White Collar Boxing">
</datalist>
        <input type="text" class="search-field location" placeholder="Location?">
        <button class="search-button" type="button">search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to describe.  You have two forms here (incidentally, you've placed one of them in the JavaScript section of your code snippet, making the snippet an error), which one are you using?  How are these two forms related?  What specifically are you expecting that form to do when it's submitted?  What specifically is happening instead?

Comment: Hi david, thankyou for getting back to me. I probably shouldnt of entered the javascript code as this is not mine, just something similar to what i am trying to achieve. Im trying to have the html datalist open a popup with what is selected from the datalist. Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59707645/11301900.

Comment: @AMC Isn't the duplicate above just a duplicate of this question?

Comment: @LucaNeri That other question appears to have been posted 2 hours before this one, though.

Comment: @AMC This is the only one not marked as a duplicate, the other 7 are.

Comment: @LucaNeri I'm a bit lost now, sorry. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @AMC LukePT2ME posted 7 other questions that are the same as this one. This is the only one not marked as a duplicate and the link you provided above goes to one of his duplicate questions.

Comment: @LucaNeri Indeed, do you think this one should be marked as a duplicate too?

Comment: @AMC No, as we should keep one question that isn't marked as a duplicate, so people know which one to answer. It wouldn't be fair to mark all of the questions as duplicate would it?

Comment: @LucaNeri I was thinking the same thing. I wish I hadn't messed up the chronology of duplicates, but it shouldn't be a big deal in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have added popups for each available option and have also added some JavaScript to open specific popups depending on the current selection. I have added some basic styling, a close button on each popup and have tidied up your HTML code a little bit.

```js
function goToNewPage() {
  if (document.getElementById('target').value) {
    window.location.href = document.getElementById('target').value;
  }
}

var search = document.getElementsByClassName("search-button")[0];
var datalist = document.getElementsByClassName("category")[0];
var popups = document.getElementsByClassName("popup");
search.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var popupsLength = popups.length;
  for (let x = 0; x < popupsLength; x++) {
    popups[x].style.display = "none";
  }

  var popup = document.getElementsByClassName("popup " + datalist.value)[0];
  popup.style.display = "block";
});

var exit = document.getElementsByClassName("exit");
var exitLength = exit.length;
for (let x = 0; x < exitLength; x++) {
  exit[x].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.target.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  max-height: 750px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #dd3333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.exit:hover {
  background: #ee4444;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <form name="dropdown">
      <select name="selected" id="target" accesskey="E">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select...</option>
        <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
        <option value="http://www.search.com/">Search.com</option>
        <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/">Dogpile</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.selected)">
    </form>

    <form>
      <div class="form-box">
        <input list="category" class="search-field category" placeholder="What service are you looking for?">
        <datalist id="category">
                        <input type="hidden">
                        <option value="General Fitness">
                        <option value="Boxing">
                        <option value="Yoga">
                        <option value="Mixed Martial Arts">
                        <option value="White Collar Boxing">
                    </datalist>
        <input type="text" class="search-field location" placeholder="Location?">
        <button class="search-button" type="button">search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="popup General Fitness">
    <h1>General Fitness</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque id ligula pretium tellus molestie rhoncus vel in leo. Aenean varius justo elit, sed euismod leo sagittis at. Fusce varius interdum consectetur. Ut id interdum nisi. Fusce mollis
      et mi nec lobortis. Praesent ac turpis dignissim, interdum nulla ac, euismod augue. In sodales lobortis quam at ultrices. Donec id scelerisque sapien. Integer leo massa, aliquet ac est ut, mollis porttitor sem. Maecenas sed tellus elit. Aliquam
      fringilla posuere urna vitae imperdiet. Sed ultricies, lectus quis tempor efficitur, dolor enim vestibulum mauris, in laoreet lorem ligula eget nisl.</p>
    <span class="exit">&#x2716;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="popup Boxing">
    <h1>Boxing</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque id ligula pretium tellus molestie rhoncus vel in leo. Aenean varius justo elit, sed euismod leo sagittis at. Fusce varius interdum consectetur. Ut id interdum nisi. Fusce mollis
      et mi nec lobortis. Praesent ac turpis dignissim, interdum nulla ac, euismod augue. In sodales lobortis quam at ultrices. Donec id scelerisque sapien. Integer leo massa, aliquet ac est ut, mollis porttitor sem. Maecenas sed tellus elit. Aliquam
      fringilla posuere urna vitae imperdiet. Sed ultricies, lectus quis tempor efficitur, dolor enim vestibulum mauris, in laoreet lorem ligula eget nisl.</p>
    <span class="exit">&#x2716;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="popup Yoga">
    <h1>Yoga</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque id ligula pretium tellus molestie rhoncus vel in leo. Aenean varius justo elit, sed euismod leo sagittis at. Fusce varius interdum consectetur. Ut id interdum nisi. Fusce mollis
      et mi nec lobortis. Praesent ac turpis dignissim, interdum nulla ac, euismod augue. In sodales lobortis quam at ultrices. Donec id scelerisque sapien. Integer leo massa, aliquet ac est ut, mollis porttitor sem. Maecenas sed tellus elit. Aliquam
      fringilla posuere urna vitae imperdiet. Sed ultricies, lectus quis tempor efficitur, dolor enim vestibulum mauris, in laoreet lorem ligula eget nisl.</p>
    <span class="exit">&#x2716;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="popup Mixed Martial Arts">
    <h1>Mixed Martial Arts</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque id ligula pretium tellus molestie rhoncus vel in leo. Aenean varius justo elit, sed euismod leo sagittis at. Fusce varius interdum consectetur. Ut id interdum nisi. Fusce mollis
      et mi nec lobortis. Praesent ac turpis dignissim, interdum nulla ac, euismod augue. In sodales lobortis quam at ultrices. Donec id scelerisque sapien. Integer leo massa, aliquet ac est ut, mollis porttitor sem. Maecenas sed tellus elit. Aliquam
      fringilla posuere urna vitae imperdiet. Sed ultricies, lectus quis tempor efficitur, dolor enim vestibulum mauris, in laoreet lorem ligula eget nisl.</p>
    <span class="exit">&#x2716;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="popup White Collar Boxing">
    <h1>White Collar Boxing</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque id ligula pretium tellus molestie rhoncus vel in leo. Aenean varius justo elit, sed euismod leo sagittis at. Fusce varius interdum consectetur. Ut id interdum nisi. Fusce mollis
      et mi nec lobortis. Praesent ac turpis dignissim, interdum nulla ac, euismod augue. In sodales lobortis quam at ultrices. Donec id scelerisque sapien. Integer leo massa, aliquet ac est ut, mollis porttitor sem. Maecenas sed tellus elit. Aliquam
      fringilla posuere urna vitae imperdiet. Sed ultricies, lectus quis tempor efficitur, dolor enim vestibulum mauris, in laoreet lorem ligula eget nisl.</p>
    <span class="exit">&#x2716;</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```